# Invalid key on activation and password reset

Tags: user-registration, authentication, password

I am in a pickle now, about to release a Wordpress-based app and I can't get the registration complete because password set/reset key is **sometimes** invalid.

I say sometimes because when the user is registered, he gets link to set the password, and that is always invalid. Then he is asked to enter his username to reset the password and a new email is sent. That link is also invalid, however, if he requests a new password reset email again, then the link is valid.

The problem seems to be the key generated. When they key is clean of symbols, it works, example:

`https://www.example.com/account/reset/?key=f2XFLHJGvemH&id=209`

When the key is with symbols, it gets denied, example:

`https://www.example.com/account/reset/?key=%sPRkgT7fW%5D@&id=209`

I disabled all plugins and it acts the same way. No caching plugins installed.

What could be happening here? Please help!

**Edit:**

I repĺicated this behavior again to make sure, and this time it took 4 tries. So I am guessing that if you keep trying to get a clean key, it works. Why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!

I had a filter hooked onto `random_password` filter to generate passwords with custom rules and `get_password_reset_key` uses the function `wp_generate_password` to generate the key, and that is why I was getting the behavior I was getting. Allz I had to do was to remove my filter from it, and bada bing bada boom, it works.